# how to convert sql query to django queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

i have two tables like categories and items  in models items has foreign key of categories,here we have 4 categories and 12 items where each category has 3 items how to write a query set to get query set to get items with same category
i know how to write Sql query (`select * from category where category_id =1;`). how to write it in d'jango query set.

Comment: Why are you thinking in terms of columns and SQL? You should be thinking in terms of your models. And since this is almost the simplest thing you can do, what was not covered in the tutorial that left you confused about how to do this?

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: You defined a column named `category_id` in a `category` table? Isn't it better to make it `id` here? Shouldn't this be `SELECT * FROM item WHERE category_id = 1`

Comment: i named it as category,but  it is a foreignkey field so thats why is is saved as category_id in database

Comment: @ganeshs this is a really basic and largely documented feature of Django's ORM. if you don't take some time doing the official tutorial and browsing the doc so you get the big picture and know where to look for for more in-depth details, you will spend even more time asking basic questions (which will be systematically downvoted) and you can be sure your code will be of very low quality since you won't have learned all of the useful features and how/when to use them.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using [Django Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/queries/):

```
Item.objects.filter(category__id=1)
```

Comment: but my column name is category and in database it is saving like category_id

Comment: and also need to write queryset based on item id only

Comment: AFAIK both `category__id=1` and `category_id=1` (single underscore) should be fine :-)

Comment: @ganeshs `Item.objects.filter(id=1)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Kamil's answer, you could use [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) or if you want to use SQL query as is, you could also use [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries). An example (taken from official docs) -

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    birth_date = models.DateField(...)
```

And querying it would be -

```
# querying with SQL raw query
for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
```

And in your case -

```
# assuming your query is correct
Item.objects.raw('select * from category where myapp_category_id = 1')
```